# Compare dates in T-SQL

Tags: sql, date, t-sql, datetime, varchar

I have a table with a column `date` of datatype `varchar`. The values are `'2022-03-08 07:00',2022-03-08 07:30 ...` .

In my stored procedure I have a parameter of type `DATE` and with a value `'2022-3-8'`

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '2022-3-8'

SELECT *, r.date AS date, @d AS d 
FROM Readings AS r
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.date, 23) = @d
```

How can I compare these two? I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I would like to remove time component and compare `'2022-03-08'` vs `'2022-3-8'`. Notice leading zero in month and day numbers.

Comment: Why do you store dates in a varchar _column_?

Comment: It's not me, but I have to use this table.

Comment: Have you tried to see if you don't have any date that are in a wrong format ? Doing this "SELECT case when CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2022-03-08 07:00', 23) = @d then 1 else 0 end " works. So maybe a wrong format in your datatable ?

Comment: Note `where function(column) = ...` is *unsargable* and will force SQL Server to scan all rows.

Comment: If `r.date` is already a varchar, converting to varchar seems redundant. You'd be better of converting to a date, e.g. `TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, r.Date, 23)`. With that being said, you'd still have an issue since your parameter is `DATE` yet your data contains time, so you may want to convert your varchar to just `DATE`

Comment: You could probably use `WHERE r.date LIKE CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @d, 23), '%')` to solve your immediate problem ([example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b87e9237752eff852ab68acf79efc742), but it is not pretty and won't scale well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` will convert your string into date and return null if that is not possible.

```
SELECT *, TRY_CAST(r.date AS DATE) as date, @d AS d
FROM Readings r
WHERE TRY_CAST(r.date AS DATE) = @d
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '2022-3-8';
WITH Readings AS 
(
    SELECT '2022-03-08 07:00' AS date  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2022-03-08 07:30'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-03-06 17:30' --will be false
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-02-31 07:30' --invalid string
)
SELECT r.date as OriginalString
, TRY_CAST(r.date AS DATE) as CastDate
, TRY_CONVERT(DATE,r.date,23) as ConvertDate
, @d AS d
, CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(r.date AS DATE) = @d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Matched
FROM Readings r
```

Comment: Thanks! `WHERE TRY_CAST(r.date AS DATE) = @d` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use **right(replicate('0',2)+value,2)** that enables you to change a *1 one_digit number* to *two_digit number*(*1=>01*).
use **PARSENAME** for *split* and **concat** for *connect strings*

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '2022-3-8'

SELECT Concat(( Parsename(Replace(@d, '-', '.'), 3) )/*year*/, '-', RIGHT(
              Replicate('0', 2) + ( Parsename(Replace(@d, '-', '.'), 2) ), 2)
       /*month*/,
              '-', RIGHT(Replicate('0', 2) + ( Parsename(Replace(@d, '-', '.'),
                                               1) ), 2
                   )/*day*/) as d
```

or in your query

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '2022-3-8'

SELECT *,
       r.date
       AS date,
       ,@d
FROM   readings AS r
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.date, 23) = 
Concat(( Parsename(Replace(@d, '-', '.'), 3) )/*year*/, '-', RIGHT(
       Replicate('0', 2) + ( Parsename(Replace(@d, '-', '.'), 2) ), 2)/*month*/,
       '-',
       RIGHT(Replicate('0', 2) + ( Parsename(Replace(@d, '-', '.'), 1) ), 2)
       /*day*/)
```

Comment: Your query to pad the date with `0` is needlessly complicated, since `@d` is already a date and not a string, you can get the same result with simply `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @d, 23)`. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4fb73c50c962498d8b1fd889274d942). You also can't reference `d` in your where clause, as this is just an alias for a column in the select

Comment: I change it thanks for your mention